# Inserting non-modifiable text to a vim buffer

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there any way to insert non-modifiable text to a modifiable buffer. I want to change the syntax highlighting of the inserted text too if it is possible.

Example (what I want to to achieve):

The content of the buffer:

```
text...
/* this is a script which can be replaced
the second line of the script */
other text...
```

I highlight the second and the third line and run my plugin which replaces the lines to a non-modifiable text.

```
text...
[non-modifiable text]
other text...
```

If I run my plugin on the non-modifiable text again, it replaces back to its original content.

```
text...
/* this is a script which can be replaced
the second line of the script */
other text...
```

Comment: A buffer is either modifiable or non-modifiable. If you want to mix the two you will have to come up with your own modifiable/non-modifiable routine.

Comment: Can you explain it how can I start this? Also I edited my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enforce that Vim commands do not change certain lines. A buffer can only be "locked" completely, but clearing the `'modifiable'` option.

The best you can achieve is restoring the original contents of those lines. This can be done via `:autocmd`. A suitable trigger event would be `BufWritePre`; changes can be made, but will revert immediately before persisting the buffer. Demo:

```
:autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call setline(2, '[non-modifiable text]')
```

For highlighting, you can either extend *syntax highlighting*, or use the (window-local) `:match` that goes on top of syntax:

```
:match NonText /^\[non-modifiable text\]$/
```